# Mysql query assembling

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a Mysql query in which where condition has a string.i am unable to build query.

i have tried this code.

```
package doubts;

public class Doubts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sb = "select * from a where b = ";
        String a = "abc";
        System.out.println(sb+a);
    }

}
```

the query which i am being able to build with the above code is:

```
select * from a where b = abc
```

i want:

```
select * from a where b = "abc"
```

i will like to have a solution to this problem.

Comment: What is the output you get? How is it *wrong*? Have you tried escaping double quotes, like `String a = "\"abc\"";`?

Comment: `System.out.println(sb+"\""+a+"\"");` , but you'd better use a `PreparedStatement` .

Answer (score 0):

Like deHaar and Arnaud already wrote:

Put your `a` in double quotes.

e.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sb = "select * from a where b = ";
    String a = "\"abc\"";
    System.out.println(sb+a);
}
```

Even better: when executing this query on a database, use `PreparedStatement`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);) {
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from a where b = ?");) {
             pstmt.setString(1, "abc");
            try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```